# Find smallest value with tolerance

Tags: r

How would you find the last lowest value in this vector with a certain tolerance without changing the order?

Example:

```
c(0, 785, 10273, 6231, 5417, 2328, 5249, 1725, 2656, 6258, 2687, 
2651, 1063, 325, 2556, 738, 631, 140, 57, 1173, 407, 225, 135, 
69, 81, 21, 16, 3, 0, 26, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Assume a tolerance of 26.  Working backwards from the last element (0) I would like to return the position of the number with tolerance greater than 26 from the previous number.  In this example it would be position 30, or the number 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this:

```
tail(which(diff(x)>=26),1L)+1L;
## [1] 30
```

**Data**

```
x <- c(0,785,10273,6231,5417,2328,5249,1725,2656,6258,2687,2651,1063,325,2556,738,631,140,57,
1173,407,225,135,69,81,21,16,3,0,26,1,2,0,1,2,1,1,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0);
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  What if I also wanted to check and make sure all other data points fit this rule?  So all other points are greater than 26.  In this example it would be position 26.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Position` with the `right=TRUE` argument to avoid having to search forwards and then take the last result:

```
Position(identity, diff(x) >= 26, right=TRUE) + 1
#[1] 30
```

Comment: +1 Smart solution, `Position()` is a rather obscure function. Could speed it up slightly by replacing `isTRUE` with `identity`.